# How do I do a count from 2 different tables then sum them both for a total?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

Say for example I have 2 tables called `"TABLE_ZOO"` AND `"TABLE_VET"`
containing the same column called `"Animals"`.

Firstly I want to count all the Animals in both tables
Secondly I then want to do a sum and get a numerical value as the output.

> so if animals in Zoo = 10
>
> and VET = 4 My result should say 14

Comment: I noticed you tried to edit my answer to respond, please use the "add a comment" button, under the answer to respond with your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make use of *subqueries* to get the result that you desire.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_ZOO(id int(11), animal varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE TABLE_VET(id int(11), animal varchar(100));

INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(1, 'Lion');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(2, 'Zebra');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(3, 'Penguin');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(4, 'Polar Bear');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(5, 'Dolphin');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(6, 'Shark');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(7, 'Cheeta');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(8, 'Panda');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(9, 'Monkey');
INSERT INTO TABLE_ZOO VALUES(10, 'Gorilla');

INSERT INTO TABLE_VET VALUES(1, 'Cat');
INSERT INTO TABLE_VET VALUES(2, 'Dog');
INSERT INTO TABLE_VET VALUES(3, 'Hamster');
INSERT INTO TABLE_VET VALUES(4, 'Fish');
```

Example SQL:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(id)
 FROM TABLE_ZOO) as ZOO_COUNT,
(SELECT COUNT(id)
 FROM TABLE_VET) as VET_COUNT,
((SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM TABLE_ZOO))+
((SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM TABLE_VET)) as TOTAL_COUNT
FROM TABLE_ZOO
LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

[image: SQL Test]

SQL Test Link [here](https://sqltest.net/#442977).

So what I am basically doing here is making subqueries and giving them meaningful aliases so that we know which count is which.

Some basic information about subqueries [here](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php).

Comment: I got the solution i need by doing the following:-

Comment: SELECT
((SELECT COUNT(Animals) FROM Table_ZOO)+
(SELECT COUNT(Animals) from Table_VET))
AS Volume FROM DUAL;

Comment: @Adas he already accepted my answer, which is more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT (Select Count(*) from Table_Zoo) + (Select Count(*) from Table_VET) as Total
```

Then set your filters according to what you need inside the brackets